# get value from hashtable where key is ArrayList<String>, and lookup is String

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hashtable

I went to send the hashtable a string, and have it check it's keys (which are ArrayList). If the ArrayList contains the given String, return the value of the key.

```
package com;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class TestMain {
    private static final String str1 = "n";
    private static final String str2 = "north";
    private static final Hashtable<ArrayList<String>,String> compassDirection = new Hashtable<ArrayList<String>,String>() {{
        put(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("n", "north")), "North");
        put(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("s", "south")), "South");
        put(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("e", "east")), "East");
        put(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("w", "west")), "West");
    }};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // print str1 as "North" from hashtable call
        // print str2 as "North" from hashtable call
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would the key be a list? It's not like you can call `get("n")` or `get("north")` to lookup the `"North"` value. If that's what you want, you need to add two entries: `put("n", "North")` and `put("north", "North")`

Comment: Don't use lists as your keys.  Just use a `HashMap<String,String>` and put each value in as many times as there are keys for it.

Comment: @Andreas I guess I'll do that as a workaround. But in the future, it would be nice to know if I could use ArrayList<> with Contains as a key... especially if I am handling large arrays.

Comment: It's not so much a workaround. It's just using a hashtable correctly instead of wrongly. The hashtable needs to know the hash of the key you are looking for in order to find it. That's the whole mechanism by which hashtables work. If you store a list as a key, you need to provide the list again to look it up, because without that, you don't know the correct hash.

Comment: @FiddleFreak No, you can't do that.  It's just not how maps work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the workaround I'm using for now is the following...

```
package com;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class TestMain {
    private static final String str1 = "n";
    private static final String str2 = "north";
    private static final Hashtable<String,String> compassDirection = new Hashtable<String,String>() {{
        put("n", "North");
        put("north", "North");
        put("s", "South");
        put("south", "South");
        put("e", "East");
        put("east", "East");
        put("w", "West");
        put("west", "West");
    }};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(compassDirection.get(str1));
        System.out.println(compassDirection.get(str2));
    }
}
```

But it would still be nice to know if the question using ArrayList is doable.

Comment: That is not a *workaround*. It is the only way to use a `Map`, because you have to provide the *full key* to do a lookup. A `Map` is like an index at the end of a book. The index is organized (alphabetical, similar to how a `TreeMap` is organized) so you can quickly find an entry. If you tried to add an entry `[Uno, One, Ein] -> Page 7`, where would you add it? You can't! You add 3 entries: `Uno -> Page 7`, `One -> Page 7`, `Ein -> Page 7`, so you can quickly find either of those words in the index. What you're asking makes no sense to how maps work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Multimap from Guava. You can populate it with key="North" and values ["n", "north"].  Then call invert on the Multimap, that gives you another map with key="n" with values ["North"] and key ="north" with values=["North"].  That lets you enter the values with the format you want, then generate from that a map that lets you do lookups like you want.

Alternatively enter the values similarly to above but use a

```
 Map<String, List<String>>
```

and write your own invert method that returns a

```
Map<String, String>.
```

Comment: @Andreas: yes, I am. that seems to fit the data the OP is giving as an example. If the values aren’t unique no solution is going to work.